# IBM Notes / Domino: replication report showing weird numbers

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

it's not often that I'm seeing this, but it's not been the first time either:

[image: Screenshot of Replication error]

my personal log file doesn't give any helpful information, only the usual figures.

Anyone having an idea what could be causing this?

Facts: it's been a replication between two servers that I triggered manually through my Notes Client; both servers are the exact same version (9.0.1 FP6).

Comment: This is a normal "hickup" of the replication- process. This happens from time to time. Just ignore it, that's what I do since almost 20 years now...

Comment: thanks for re-assuring me; as I wrote: I've seen this from time to time. But since we're currently fighting with other (partially massive) Designer related problems I got a bit nervous